# Trying to assign Wordpress post on user when registers

Tags: php, wordpress, backend

I'm currently working on a counselling website. My current issue I am having is getting WordPress to assign a wordpress post to a user when they register.

1) user clicks on link, this then takes them to the wordpress register page(standard wordpress register).

link build up 
`"wp-login.php?action=register&post=4150"`

2) once they're register I look on the post itself, and the author is still admin.

My code:

```php
function on_user_register( $user_id ) {
    $id = $_GET['post'];
    $post = get_post($id);
    if($id){
      $update_creator = array(
                  'ID'          => $id, //created post ID
                  'post_author' => $user_id
              );

      wp_update_post( $update_creator );
  }
}

add_action( 'user_register', 'on_user_register', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My immediate guess is that the `$_GET` variable is getting removed when the user submits the page because it is submitting the form using `POST`. You'll need to either modify the registration form to submit your variable to the form, or find another mechanism of bringing the information over (sessions? cookies? etc)

Comment: is there anyway I could check to see if the ```$_get``` variable is being removed?

Comment: @JamesThomasChaplin You can dump the entire array by doing `print_r($_GET); die;`. This should stop you during the registration process and output what is going on in that variable. You can also check your network tab in your browser's console to find the `POST` request and see what is being sent with it.

Comment: Thanks mate, I fixed it by setting a cookie.